# how to pass variable from controller to directive using click event in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

i am using directive concept in angularjs to pass data varible from controller to directive.i am writing one html page and controller,directive in angularjs.

test.html:

```
<div ng-controller="myController"
      data-angular-treeview="true"
      data-tree-model="roleList"
      data-node-id="roleId"
      data-tree-id="mytree"
      data-node-label="roleName"
      data-node-children="children" 
      data-ng-click="selectNode(currentNode)"
      >
    </div>
```

testcontroller.js:

```
(function(){
    app.controller('myController', function($scope,$http,TreeService){
        $scope.selectNode=function(val)
        {
            $scope.nodeval=val.roleName;
            alert("select:"+$scope.nodeval);
        };
  });

})();
```

testdirective.js:

```
app.directive('tree1', function($rootScope) {
    function compile(scope, element, attributes) {
        return {
                post:function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {

                    iElement.bind('click', function() {
                        alert("click: "+scope.node);
                    });
                }
        };
    }

    return {
        compile: compile,
        scope: {

         },
           restrict: 'AE',
    };
});
```

here i am getting selected node  name in testcontroller.js but i want to pass that nodename in my directive so please suggest me how to this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What i would do is define inside the directive isolated scope an attribute like this:

```
scope: {
    node: '='
}
```

And inside the view controller have a node initialized as $scope.node = {}; and with the click event change the value of the local $scope.node to the node you are interested in, and as the directive recieved the reference to the $scope.node attribute inside the view controller, it would automatically update itself

Answer (score 0):

```
<div test-directive node-value="node"></div>
```

isolate scope directive:

```
directive('testDirective', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            nodeValue: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
           console.log(scope.nodeValue);
       }
}
```

Access controller scope:

```
directive('testDirective', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
           console.log(scope.$eval(attrs['nodeValue']));
       }
}
```